# Program to compute the average of values: if to test chars

Tags: c, arrays, char

Please, take a look at a program that prompts the user to enter 3 values and computes the average of these values. 
I decided to add a test condition that checks if the user has entered a number or a character.

```
// a program that calculates the average of an array of 3 floating-point values; with for loop

#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    float values[3];
    float element;
    float sum = 0;
    int i;

    printf ("Please, enter 3 floating values:  \n");

    for ( i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        if (scanf ("%f", &element) == 1)
        {
            if ( (element >= 'a' && element <= 'z') || (element >= 'A' && element <= 'Z') )
                printf ("Sorry, you have entered letters\n");

            else if (element <= 0)
                printf ("Please, enter positive values\n");

            else
                values[i] = element;
                sum += values[i];
        }
    }

    printf ("The average of 3 values is %.2f\n", sum / 3);

    return 0;
}
```

When I run the program, I get the following problems:
1) it seem to work with positive numbers;

2) when I try to enter negative numbers, the program does print the required statement, but the result is still incremented into i, hence lowering the number of further entries; also, even if the number is negative, the program still comes up with some average nonsense value.

```
Please, enter 3 floating values:  
-75
Please, enter positive values
98
Sorry, you have entered letters
-786.9
Please, enter positive values
The average of 3 values is 2087205705198174400484999168
```

3) when I test the program with letters, it still returns some average, though a zero one:

```
Please, enter 3 floating values:  
jklj
The average of 3 values is 0.00
```

I would be grateful for your help!

Comment: what about if element is a dot (.) or a slash or something else not between a and z. should use logic that tries to convert to float and throw the error when not..

Answer (score 2):

1. Your `element` will never contain letters, since you've declared it as float and scanned it as float. If you wish to know if you were given a letters, you should read a string, test it, and only then convert it to float (comparing `element` to `'a'` is actually comapring it to the ASCII code of `'a'` = 97).
2. About the wrong sum - you forgot the curly braces for your `else` block. Change it to:

   ```
   else {
       values[i] = element;
       sum += values[i];
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your program to end if negative numbers are entered you can use the return statement or deincrement the  value of i for more cases. As for letter it never enters the if block so you can use an else. Try the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    float values[3];
    float element;
    float sum = 0;
    int i;
    printf ("Please, enter 3 floating values:  \n");
    for ( i = 0; i < 3; i++)
          {
              if (scanf ("%f", &element) == 1)
                    {
                         if (element <= 0)
                            {
                                 printf ("Please, enter positive values\n");
                                 i--; // or use the return statement
                             }
                        else
                           {
                                 values[i] = element;
                                sum += values[i];
                           }
                       }
               else
                  {
                         printf("You entered special characters");
                         return;
                   }
    }
   printf ("The average of 3 values is %.2f\n", sum / 3);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much. It did work, and I see my mistakes now. The only issue still left is the decrementing one: before your post I have tried `i -= i; `, and got an error message; now I've tried `i--;` (which I assume should have the same meaning), and still get an error message: `ex6-4.c: In function ‘main’:
ex6-4.c:22: error: expected expression before ‘else’`

Comment: i-=i subtacts i from i resulting in i becoming 0. What you can do is i-=1 that is same as i-- . And your error is not related to this. You are probably missing an if statement.